# Php Mysql Update

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have some code that I am trying to make into a news feed for my front page. So far I cant get the Update to work. Ps feel free to clean up code and make for practical as this is version 1 I haven't cleaned code up. Thanks Joshua

Update Part

```
    if(isset($_POST['edit']))
    {
    $checkbox = $_POST['checkbox'];

    for($i=0;$i<count($_POST['checkbox']);$i++){

    $edit_id = $checkbox[$i];

        echo "<textarea name='editsavetext' id='editsavetext' rows='4' cols='50'>$edit_id</textarea>";
    }};

    if(isset($_POST['editsave'])){

    echo $editsavetext;

    $editsavetext = $_POST['editsavetext'];

    $sql='UPDATE $tbl_name SET home_show = $editsavetext WHERE home_show = $edit_id';

    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    if($result){
echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; url=http://****' />";}};
```

For Rich Bradshaw

Well at the moment the code doesnt work because i need the system to remember what checkbox was ticks and what is being edited using $edit_id because it doesnt remember the results when being saved so it doesnt effect anything as such.

```
if(isset($_POST['edit']))
{
$checkbox = $_POST['checkbox'];

for($i=0;$i<count($_POST['checkbox']);$i++){

$edit_id = $checkbox[$i];

    echo "<textarea name='editsavetext' id='editsavetext' rows='4' cols='50'>$edit_id</textarea>";
}};

if(isset($_POST['editsave'])){

echo $editsavetext;

$editsavetext = $_POST['editsavetext'];

$sql="UPDATE `$tbl_name` SET home_show = '$editsavetext' WHERE home_show=':edit_id'";

$result = mysql_query($sql);

if($result){echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; url=http://****' />";}};
```

Comment: If you change your query to `$sql="UPDATE $tbl_name SET home_show = '$editsavetext' WHERE home_show = '$edit_id'";`, will it work?

Comment: Note: the `mysql_*` functions are deprecated and will be removed from future versions of PHP. You should not write new code using them. Use `mysqli_*` or PDO instead.

Answer (score 1):

Without digging through all of that,

```
'UPDATE $tbl_name SET home_show = $editsavetext WHERE home_show = $edit_id'
```

should be

```
"UPDATE `$tbl_name` SET home_show = '$editsavetext' WHERE home_show = $edit_id"
```

if you had code like:

```
$a = "hi";

echo 'I say $a';
```

it would write out `I say $a`.

if you had

```
echo "I say $a";
```

it would write `I say hi`.

Also, text needs to be in speechmarks in SQL queries.

Then you need to look up SQL Injection, as this code is not safe to use without protecting against it. Finally, why are you using `mysql_query`? Read the docs on it: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php - note that it's deprecated.

[image]

Comment: Oops.. `home_show='$edit_id'`. I understand, you eagerly wants to post your answer. ;)

Comment: I wouldn't bother doing that as it's an integer.

Comment: At this point you need to check through the rest of the code and make sure you haven't made the same/similar mistakes elsewhere. Reduce your code to just the sql part, does that work? If so, this problem is solved, but you have more problems.

Comment: I worked out the problem is inserting the output $edit_id into it but i havn't fixed it yet

Comment: I'd assumed that $edit_id was an integer, if not, then wrap that in speechmarks too.

Comment: $edit_id is the item selected to edit using checkboxs before the edit box comes up then when u save it should use $edit_id in the update

Comment: any ideas yet about it

Comment: I'm not really sure what you are asking, but I'm working now - sorry.

Comment: Read up above Rich Bradshaw i have told you the problem :) please try to come up with a fix

Comment: please try to come up with a fix

Comment: when would u be able to help

Answer (score 0):

Your update statement seems to be wrong.
You are using single quotes and using `$edit_id` inside it. Use double quotes for that.
Try this (Assuming that home_show are ints.)-

```
$sql="UPDATE $tbl_name SET home_show = $editsavetext WHERE home_show = $edit_id";
     ^                                                                         ^
```

Assuming home_show column is varchar

```
$sql="UPDATE $tbl_name SET home_show = '$editsavetext' WHERE home_show = '$edit_id'";
     ^                                 ^             ^                   ^        ^^
```